# Is it possible to create private cards in a public Trello board?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

I created a public Trello board, but I want to create some private cards which are only visible to me (Admin). Is it possible to do directly in the public board or is there any other workaround for this purpose?

It is just like [internal reference cards](https://trello.com/c/ScRdhdKA/1518-trello-card-picker-for-other-apps) in [the Trello development board](https://trello.com/b/nC8QJJoZ/trello-development), however it is only useful in describing a related private card in another board to the related members. Creating another private board would be redundant.

Answer (score 3):

You can't create private cards - a workaround is to create a private board, and refer to the card by adding a link to the card in the private board n the description.

Your example does pretty much that

Comment: Thanks. My example above is only useful in describing a related private card in another board to the related members. By creating another private board would be redundant and boards can never be deleted, but just archived.

Answer (score -1):

There is a 3rd party service called CardSync that sort of does this, if you want to use a 3rd party.

https://trello.com/cardsync

This shares a version of your card at the moment of sharing with another party while keeping the card private.

Comment: link is not longer valid